Can we use decomposed time series in a test set to obtain models accuracy metrics?
Currently I'm cross validating (rolling time window, different test lengths) several forecast models to obtain performance comparison on highly skewed time series (due to true ocassional outliers). My goal is to tell which models will get the best extraction of "true" (median) signal (which is sinusoidal-like - with strong seasonality) from original time series using MAE (accuracy) and ME (bias). Hence I forecast using models based on original data and I compare it with decomposed data (sum of trend+seasonality).
I'm aware that seasonal and trend component are unobservable and the decomposition will never get me "true" signal but in general how erroneous this approach is?
As well I'm aware of cross validation on simulated data from given distribution or outliers treatment but it's not my point.
